# how merage and remove this array

Tags: arrays

I would combin two array php

```
$a=array (
'1.1.1.1' => '2020-08-03',
'1.1.1.2' => '2020-08-09',
)
```

```
$b=array (
'1.1.1.1' => '2020-08-11',
'1.1.2.3' => '2020-08-11',
)
```

If ip address present in both array and ip if not exist in first array remve key.

**I want the output array to be like the bottom array**

```
Array (
'1.1.1.1' => '2020-08-03',
'1.1.2.3' => '2020-08-11',
)
```

Comment: Is this a PHP question?

Answer (score 0):

```
**this code nearby your answer change check it's it working for me**



    
<?php
    $a=array (
    '1.1.1.1' => '2020-08-03',
    '1.1.1.2' => '2020-08-09',
    );
    
    $b=array (
    '1.1.1.1' => '2020-08-11',
    '1.1.2.3' => '2020-08-11',
    );
    
    // $c;
    $c=array_merge($a,$b);
      $len=count($c);
    var_dump($c);
    // for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
    //   echo $c[$x];
    //   echo "<br>";
    // }
    foreach ($c as $d) {
        # code...
        echo $d;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>


**output**
2020-08-11
2020-08-09
2020-08-11
```

**This value display in array**

Comment: thanks for reply , but im want remove '1.1.1.2' => '2020-08-09', from final array